# MySQL Trigger concatenate multiple string into a variable

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need to concatenate string into a trigger variable, because of the conditions;

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER product_before_update 
BEFORE UPDATE 
    ON products FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN 
    DECLARE tempVar varchar(1000);

    SET tempVar := '[Product update] ' + old.name;

    IF(OLD.quantity != NEW.quantity) THEN
        tempVar += 'Quantity changed: ' . OLD.quantity . ' to ' . NEW.quantity;
    END IF
END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

So basically `tempVar` will have multiple information and I'd like to write everything on a variable so later I could add to a table of logs.

The error is on the `tempVar +=` line because it doesn't understand the + signal.

Comment: Use [CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Comment: How? Because I tried `SET tempVar := CONCAT('string..');` and then in the line below `SET tempVar := CONCAT('another string..');` and triggers error.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ');
SET tempVar := CONCAT('<ul>');`

Comment: Try `SET tempVar = CONCAT(tempVar, 'Quantity changed: ', OLD.quantity, ...)`

Comment: The error message is for code, that we don't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a sequence of [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
tempVar := CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(tempVar, 'Quantity changed: '), OLD.quantity), ' to '), NEW.quantity);
```

If `quantity` is numeric, then you need to `cast` it to `varchar`, like this:

```
tempVar := CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(tempVar, 'Quantity changed: '), CAST(OLD.quantity as varchar(50))), ' to '), CAST(NEW.quantity as varchar(50)))
```

EDIT: Paul Spiegel's constructive criticism is valid, so I add its idea into the answer

Without `CAST`:

```
tempVar := CONCAT(tempVar, 'Quantity changed: ', OLD.quantity, ' to ', NEW.quantity);
```

With `CAST`:

```
tempVar := CONCAT(tempVar, 'Quantity changed: ', CAST(OLD.quantity as varchar(50)), ' to ', CAST(NEW.quantity as varchar(50)));
```

In this answer I assumed that `OLD.quantity` and `NEW.quantity` are not `null`. If they can be `null`, then you need to check whether it is `null` and handle that case as well.

EDIT2:

We need to use the `SET` keyword before `tempVar` each time we assign a value to it.

Comment: CONCAT can take more than two parameters.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel good point, I did not know about it! I have edited my answer accordingly, thanks.

Comment: `CAST()` is also unnecessary. Numerics will be casted automatically. http://rextester.com/VOPAK80238

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I prefer to keep the code as it is after the edit to make sure it is bullet-proof. The op had a problem using CONCAT, I am not sure which MySQL version is being used and whether your statement is true in all versions.

Comment: @LajosArpad `tempVar :=` doesn't work, I need to use `SET tempVar :=` always.

Comment: @Linesofcode thank you for pointing that out, I have edited my answer to reflect that.